# Save all data of MVC4 html grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone give me an example of saving all html grid data in one time. I have a view like this.

```
@model IList<SURVEY.Models.Question>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Survey", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-3" }))
{               
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Ans1</td>
            <td align="center">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionAS_@item.QuestionId" value="1" id="optionAS_1" onclick="disableAs(this,@item.QuestionId,1)"/>                                                
                </label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optionAS_@item.QuestionId" value="2" id="optionAS_1" onclick="disableAs(this,@item.QuestionId,2)"/>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I am getting null value for these controls in controller post.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IList<Question> ques)
{         
    return View();
}
```

I am getting `ques` is `null` here. Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your View ?

Comment: I have update the question. Now it has more info about view. I want all values of radio button to my controller by  IList<Question>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use html helpers to bind properties of your model, your code might be as follows:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
     <td>@Html.HiddenFor(_ => Model[i].Id)
         Model[i].Ans1
     </td>
     <td align="center">
       <label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(_ => Model[i].Name)
       </label>
     </td>
     ...
  </tr>
}
```

and so for. HiddenFor helper is needed to create hidden input to send Id value to server to give you ability to identify you object. Take a look into [Html Helpers in MVC](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp) and you will have your model back to server when form is submitted.